# Resources for learning the nature of number and mathematics for proofs?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, logic, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I'm going through proofs and discovering that much of it relies on intuitions regarding the nature and relationship of numbers and the transformations between them.

For example, that an even number takes the form of 2m and that odd is 2n+1. Or that when a fraction is reduced the numerator and denominator can't both be even.

I understand that performing these proofs is probably the best way to learn these relationships, but are there any resources (ie., book) available that I can refer to for these common axioms?

Comment: Proofs don't rely on intuition, only on axioms, definitions and logic. Discovering a proof may rely on intuition, but...  the word essentially means "insight", and that can't be explained, it can only be acquired by doing a lot of maths (and I mean **doing** it, not watching it done, at MSE or someplace else!). So lazy students may decide whether they need it so badly.

Comment: Have a look at Landau's Foundations of Analysis (which is really about the construction of the real and complex numbers in informal set theory). The first chapter about the natural numbers should be of particular interest. If you google for it, you will find on-line PDFs of the book.

Comment: Your examples follow directly from definitions of even numbers, odd numbers and fractions in lowest terms respectively. You can look up such definitions online. See for example https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Even_Integer

Comment: thank you @RobArthan thats a great recommendation!

Comment: thank you @DanChristensen thats a great reference!

Comment: Some resources: Jürg Kramer & Anna-Maria von Pippich, [From Natural Numbers to Quaternions](https://books.google.it/books?id=nvM-DwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), Springer (2018) and Larry Gerstein, [Introduction to Mathematical Structures and Proofs](https://books.google.it/books?id=qK9y768b1NQC&printsec=frontcover), Springer (2012).

Comment: Some free, open-source textbooks are available [here](https://aimath.org/textbooks/approved-textbooks/).

Answer (score 0):

Your examples follow directly from the definitions of [even numbers](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Even_Integer), [odd numbers](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Odd_Integer) (at proofwiki.org) and [irreducible fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_fraction) (at Wikipedia). Being definitions, they do not need proofs. You can look up such definitions online. (See links)